# unexpected html closed tag meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
<td>
    {{#if isEditingTeam}}
    <form class="edit-team">
        <input type="text" name='edit' placeholder='{{name}}'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <a id='#cancel' class="text-danger">Cancel</a>
    </form>
    {{else}} {{name}}
</td>
```

I am getting an error on line 10, I'm new to Meteor.js, But I don't understand anything about this error I've looked throughout their docs and could not find anything the err is:

> client/views/team.html: 10: unexpected closed tag.

It has something to do with the `{{else}} {{name}}` line, but I don't understand why is not working, I do much of my work in Angular and Meteor is so abstract I can't wrap my head around some errors. Please explain why I'm getting that error and how it can be avoided.

Comment: Missing `{{/if}}` statement

Comment: The {{/if}} statement was outside the </td>...Just moved it back and it worked.. Thank you

Comment: I will just need 5 mins to accept. @keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement to close `if` statement is missing. Add it before the `<td>` element is closed.

```
<td>
    {{#if isEditingTeam}}
    <form class="edit-team">
        <input type="text" name='edit' placeholder='{{name}}'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <a id='#cancel' class="text-danger">Cancel</a>
    </form>
    {{else}}
        {{name}}
    {{/if}} <!-- Added This -->
</td>
```